# Is there a way to use a button in Microsoft access to enter data into a table and also clear all of the text boxes

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have been able to make a form that can add an entry to a table but I have to fill all of the fields and then press enter to do this. Also, after the data is added to the table it still remains in the text boxes. I would like to make this process more user friendly by using a button to enter all of the fields and then be ready for another entry.

Edit: Since I'm getting downvotes, can someone explain to me why my question is bad.

Comment: I'd say people are asking: "what have you tried?". And it seems you are asking two questions in one, both rather broad and with few details of your actual problem.

Comment: Consider using bound forms - they do everything you want automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The record selector should default on the bottom left corner of your form. The black arrow with the yellow star is the new record. That will blank all the fields and allow new data to be added. Your question is a little hard to follow without details. I hope this helped.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, you literally just want to clear the textboxes after you hit enter? (Your question is a little vague).

If so, for each textbox, in the `Button_Click()` event (go into "Code event builder" when you right click on the button in design mode), just say

```
FormName!YourTextBox.Text = ""
```

Please refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox) for further questions

**Also, why your question is bad:**

1. It is vague. StackOverflow (and anywhere where you'd be asking for code help) is a place where you are expected to be very specific about the errors you are getting so that others can reproduce them (imagine submitting a bug report to your favorite open source project with just the description "X doesn't work"--nobody would know what you mean or where to look for a bug.
2. You *clearly* haven't already researched this to see if the answer already existed. If your question is what I think it is (which it may not be--you weren't all that specific.), the first result on Google or DuckDuckGo would have probably answered your question. If not, it's not hard to check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.text).

P.S., I don't want to come across as harsh...just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

note that in classic Microsoft Access the forms are bound to the table - so that no Enter/Save button is needed....its entered already....

as noted it is moving to the next record - that has all new empty fields...

have had clients insist on a Save button because they are accustomed to that in the web world .... it can be set up that way with an unbound form but it's a waste of energy...